# How to add CSS-code to my Sharepoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a Sharepoint List. I need to change the font of the list in CSS-code

```
<style type="text/css">
   .ms-rtestate-write 
   {
       FONT-FAMILY: Calibri; 
       COLOR: grey; 
       FONT-SIZE: 11pt
   }
</style>
```

But how can i add the css-code to my list. My List is not on a page
so i can not use a webpart.

Greetings,

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two options

1. Formating the columns with the Column formating json [column formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#detailed-syntax-reference)
2. Creating an SPFX Solution that loads the css [Inject Custom CSS on SharePoint Online](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/10/29/update-inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-application-extensions/)

Comment: Then how can i convert the CSS to JSON?

Comment: "style": {
                  "font-family": "Calibri",
                  "color":"grey",
"font-size": "11pt"
                }